# Can't add Jenkins connector to a Teams channel - says it's already added

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, microsoft-teams

I have O365 MS Teams. I've had Jenkins Office365 Connector wokring great, and feeding the build information to a number of channels.
Then recently the Teams plugin started to report a warning:
Important: Your connector is running on old configuration. Navigate to connector configuration window to update to new configuration.

The url for the project needed to be updated. Removed the plugin from the channel. Wanted to add it again, but whenever I tried it says *this app is already added*
The connector seems to be running fine on some other build channels.
Tried adding the connector from the channel\connectors options directly, and through the *Apps* menu of Teams.
Checked the global permissions, and Jenkins plugin is not blocked.
Any ideas where to go from here?

Due to a number of projects running I'd rather not remove the whole thing alltogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for a few hours and trying again I was able to add the Jenkins Office365 connector to the channel again.
It seems there was a retention period of some sort that had prevented re-adding a freshly removed plugin.